# Package accessible from more than one module in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm trying to use google text to speech but there is a problem with the imports:

```
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.AudioConfig;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.SsmlVoiceGender;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.SynthesisInput;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.SynthesizeSpeechResponse;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.TextToSpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.VoiceSelectionParams;
```

It shows various errors where it's using the same modules from different packages:

`java: module google.cloud.texttospeech reads package com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1 from both google.cloud.texttospeech and proto.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1`

I have these requirements in my `module-info` file:

```
requires proto.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1;
requires google.cloud.texttospeech;
```

I also get a yellow warning with these requirements:

`Name of automatic module 'proto.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.`

`pom.xml` is as follows (removed project tag for clarity):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cloze</groupId>
<artifactId>cloze</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>26.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-texttospeech</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.cloze.App</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You could try removing one of the `requires` declarations.

Comment: @dan1st Without `requires google.cloud.texttospeech` I lose the `TextToSpeechClient`, without the other require I lose access to all the other imports.

Comment: @jewelsea If I remove the `module-info` file to make it non modular that does indeed solve this problem. It's true that the maintainers should create documentation for a modular app since it's really not obvious what should be used to access the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the maintainers of the google-cloud-texttospeech library and ask them to provide documentation (and perhaps an updated implementation) for using their library from a modular Java app.

In the meantime go to openjfx.io and review documentation on non-modular JavaFX apps and try following it.

Asker writes:

> If I remove the module-info file to make it non modular that does indeed solve this problem.